# vim substitute backslash

Tags: vim, backreference

I am trying to extract only the function name from a function declaration using vim script.
For testing purposes I am using this simple example:

```
int func(int a);
```

In vim script I am extracting the function name by this:

```
:let a = substitute(getline(line('.')), ".*\(func\).*", "\1", "")
```

But the backreference is not working. When I echo the variable a with

```
:echo a
```

it displays the whole line, i.e. int func(int a);

How to extract only the function name with bacreference or any other method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside double quotes, backslashes must be escaped. Either use single quotes (`'\1'`) or double all backslashes (`"\\1"`).

See `:help expr-string` for details.

Comment: I suspect that this would be the case for the match expression in addition to the replace expression, so the OP should use single quotes throughout in this case.  Quoted strings always throws me for a loop but generally these days I use double quotes only when I need to put keystrokes into the string, e.g. `"\<Esc>"`

Comment: Yes indeed. The match expression also needs single quotes.